# how to compare two java timestamps in dynamoDB

Tags: java, timestamp, amazon-dynamodb

I need to store a timestamp in dynamoDB. I then need to get that timestamp back and compare it to the current time to see if more than x minutes have passed.

- What timestamp should I use? I've seen there are multiple ones, but dynamoDB doesn't support timestamps, I'd have to be able to turn it into a string and then turn it back into a timestamp.
- once I get it back from the database I need to get a new timestamp and then use it to see how much time has passed since the first timestamp. I want to be able to say "if more than 20 minutes has passed then do this..."

I've seen that java.sql.timestamp makes it possible to compare two timestamps using .after.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Use ISO 8601 formatting, which automatically sorts in chronological order, and the Java 8 `java.time` classes (here, specifically `Instant`).

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike- "automatically sorts in chronological order" - historians are going to find that this comment is the ultimate cause of the year-9999 problem (aka the y10k problem) ;-)